# duckdb is barely utilize all the available cores in Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, duckdb

Getting inspired by this [talk](https://tele-task.de/lecture/video/10304/), I am trying to implement the same as suggested with Google Cloud Function (CF).

What I found, is the performance of running duckdb in GCS cloud function is significantly worst comparing to running it locally.

While diving deeper into it, I found that the utilization of the CPU in the CF is much worst comparing to local and to Polars within the same fucntion.

In the snippet below, I run 3 functions (that should be run internally in parallel):

1. download the files from GCS using transfer_manager.
2. run the query in duckdb.
3. run the same query in Polars.

And monitoring the cpu_percent (using psutil).
Locally (macOS i7, 8 cores, 16 GB) I run:
8 threads and it look for

- duckdb - 5 seconds with CPU percent 438.2
- Polars - 2 seconds, with CPU percent 414.6

While running in Cloud Function gen2 16 GiB, 8 cpu:

- duckdb - 26 seconds with CPU percent 100.1 (!!)
- Polars - 3 seconds with CPU percent 350.9

```
import functions_framework
import duckdb
import json
import datetime
import psutil
from functools import wraps
import os

data = {}
duckdb.query(
    f"install httpfs; load httpfs; PRAGMA enable_object_cache ; SET enable_http_metadata_cache=true;"
)
path = "./data/nyc-taxi/year=*/month=*/*.parquet"


def cpu_percent_profile(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Get the initial CPU usage percentage
        p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        initial_cpu_percent = p.cpu_percent()
        func_name = func.__name__

        data[func_name] = {}
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)

        # Get the final CPU usage percentage
        final_cpu_percent = p.cpu_percent()
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        # Print the CPU profile statistics
        print(f"Initial CPU Percent of {func_name}: {initial_cpu_percent}%")
        print(f"Final CPU Percent of {func_name}: {final_cpu_percent}%")
        print("Took {} seconds".format(end - start))
        record = data[func_name]

        record["cpu_percent"] = final_cpu_percent - initial_cpu_percent
        record["time"] = end - start

        return result

    return wrapper


@cpu_percent_profile
def download_in_parallel_from_gcs(destination_directory, threads):
    from google.cloud.storage import Client, transfer_manager

    storage_client = Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("voltrondata-labs-datasets")

    blob_names = [
        f"nyc-taxi/year=202{j}/month={i}/part-0.parquet"
        for j in range(0, 2) for i in range(1, 13) if not (j == 2 and i > 2)
    ]

    results = transfer_manager.download_many_to_path(
        bucket, blob_names, destination_directory=destination_directory, max_workers=threads, worker_type="thread"
    )

    data["download_in_parallel_from_gcs"]["threads"] = threads

    for name, result in zip(blob_names, results):

        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            print("Failed to download {} due to exception: {}".format(name, result))
        else:
            print("Downloaded {} to {}.".format(name, destination_directory + name))


@cpu_percent_profile
def query_duck(query_threads=8):
    duckdb.query(f"SET threads To {query_threads};")
    print("****************")
    print(duckdb.sql("SELECT current_setting('threads')"))
    print("****************")
    query = f"""
        SELECT 
            vendor_name,
            list(total_amount ORDER BY pickup_datetime) as rides,
            month as month,
            year as year
        FROM 
            read_parquet('{path}', hive_partitioning=true)
        WHERE 
            vendor_name is not null
        GROUP BY 
            vendor_name, 
            month,
            year
        """
    data["query_duck"]["threads"] = query_threads
    return duckdb.sql(query).pl()


@cpu_percent_profile
def query_polars(query_threads):
    os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = str(query_threads)

    import polars as pl
    print(os.getenv("POLARS_MAX_THREADS"))
    print(f"polars threads: {pl.threadpool_size()}")
    df = pl.scan_parquet(path, hive_partitioning=True)
    df = (
        df
        .filter(pl.col("vendor_name").is_not_null())
        .group_by(
            "vendor_name", "month", "year"
        )
        .agg(rides=pl.col("total_amount"))
        .collect(streaming=False)
    )
    data["query_polars"]["threads"] = query_threads
    return {
        "num_records": df.shape[0]
    }


@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    req = request.get_json()
    download_threads = req["download_threads"]
    query_threads = req["query_threads"]

    # download in parallel from gcs
    download_in_parallel_from_gcs("./data/", threads=download_threads)

    # check duckdb
    try:
        query_duck(query_threads=query_threads)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        data["query_duck"]["error"] = str(e)

    # check polars
    query_polars(query_threads=query_threads)
    return json.dumps(data, default=str)
```

As I said, I really want to implement the "Two Tier Architecture" with Duckdb (maybe later using Arrow Flight) in GCP, but first I need to figure out why my cpu is not fully utilized in CF.

Hope that someone can share what is missing.
Thanks.

Comment: It works fine (uses all available cores) if I run in Cloud Run Jobs. So I wonder what is the difference.